# Search Bar Not Showing in Some Browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, html, cross-browser

Some visitors of my site are complaining they cannot see the Search bar on my website, when they are using firefox, or some other browser.

The search bar should be at the top right menu

Link to site here : http://www.animefushigi.com/

I believe this is a CSS issue, any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: could you post the CSS that relates to the search bar please?

Answer (score 0):

Your menubar is too wide, so the searchbar placed on a new line (at least on a 1024x768 screen).

Just give #menubar a height of 80px and you can see it on the next line.

The real solution will be to give the input inside the searchbox a width. Something like 120px.

Comment: what if you try a smaller value